# Email hosting on home's Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, email-server

I am new to Server management,

I have a static Ip address

and I bought recently a domain name, I configure the domain name to target my Ip address.

I am running windows server 2003 standard.

what are the steps to host my email adresses?

Do I need to buy anything else, or what I have is enough (static ip address, domain name, win server 2003, exchange server 2003) ??

thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First run a check on your IP to make sure it is not out of a dynamic IP pool. If it is - even if you have it static - there simply is no sense, because basically, every major email server will reject you as spam. Depends on the reverse domain name for the ip address ;) Use http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to find out. There is a reverse lookup link at the end after checking your blacklist.
- Find out the reverse domain name attached to the ip address. You want to use THAT NAME as server name for email. Yes, may suck, but - a standard check for email servers is to check whether the domain name they have and the one the ip thinks it has match. No match -> spam.
- Then you need a server ;) http://www.smartertools.com/ - smartermail, free for 1 domain, 10 email addresses. Open port 25 (SMTP) and route accordingly if you have a hardware firewall. You can also use exchange, but it is really very heavy for a handfull of users. Plus it does antispam pretty badly - smartertools handles that a lot better.
- Make sure your domain IN A entry uses the name find out in my second step for MX.

FInished.